# Why do I get a ld:framework not found <frameworkName> build error during pod repo push?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I have a framework that I've built for iOS, dynamic framework with a Universal binary for x86_64 (iosSimulator), arm64 and arm64e.

The framework works fine when I drag it to an app and use it.

Pod repo push works fine when I use a repo on my machine that holds the framework and another specs repo that's on my machine. I created the repos with git init --bare

When I use github and point the spec to the github repo instead of my local repo it fails with `ld:framework not found <frameworkName>` . When I skip validation and push and and finally use it in an app using the pod file I get the same error, `ld:framework not found <frameworkName>`.

The only difference is I've moved from my local git repo that holds the framework to one on Github.

Edit:

Pasting podspec below

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name         = "frameworkName"
    s.version      = "0.51.0"
    s.summary      = "A brief description of frameworkName project."
    s.description  = <<-DESC
    An extended description of frameworkName project.
    DESC
    s.homepage     = "http://your.homepage/here"
    s.license = { :type => 'Copyright', :text => <<-LICENSE
                   Copyright 2018
                   Permission is granted to...
                  LICENSE
                }
    s.author             = { "myname" => "" }
    s.source       = { :git => "<git hub repo>", :tag => "#{s.version}", :branch => "iOS_Framework" }

    s.ios.vendored_frameworks = "frameworkName.framework"
    s.vendored_frameworks = "frameworkName.framework"
    s.ios.deployment_target  = '12.0'
    s.pod_target_xcconfig   = { 'VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'x86_64' }
    s.user_target_xcconfig  = { 'VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'x86_64' }
end
```

Comment: @Yonat Pasted thanks

Is it case sensitive by any chance. I noticed that my Upload to the git repo was frameworkName.Framework . Although I'm not sure how it worked locally.

Comment: @Yonat This is a binary framework and is not expected to be built from source. I had the source_files pointing to the headers at one point. DId not help.

Comment: @Yonat  That's not correct, Binary frameworks should have source pointing to the binary. Source can be from git, svn, zip from CDN etc. SourceFIles point to code, which probably points to headers in this case.

It's not either/or 

You had your headers in a non standard location which is why you needed it.

Comment: You're contradicting your own example. Source can bit a github repo or a zip-url as you call it.

Comment: No you don't . I have a working framework that says otherwise. My headers are in a default location.

Comment: Will do. I did have it initially and removed it while experimenting. I remember it as not helping. Will update.

Comment: Can confirm works without. Had headers in the default .framework/Headers location

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being a case sensitivity problem. The framework on the repo was named frameworkName.Framework instead of frameworkName.framework. Worked after I changed it.

Not sure why there wasn't an issue with a local git repo.